# Docker issue: /bin/sh: pip: not found

Tags: python, docker, pip, ironpython

So my dockerfile is :

```
FROM iron/python:2.7

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

Recently though when I build my image with:
    `docker build --no-cache -t <image name>:<tag>`

I run into the issue of:

```
Step 4/6 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
---> Running in 00c781a53487
/bin/sh: pip: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

was there any changes to docker that might have caused this? Because last week this was all fine and there were no issues building the image with the same exact code.

Comment: Install pip first.

Comment: `easy_install pip`

Answer (score 21):

For Python3:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install python3-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

*If you install `python-pip` for Python2 as well, you need to use `pip3` for Python3 and `pip` for Python2. But with this setting, `pip` is the same as `pip3`. Check with `pip -V`.*

Thats it :-)

Comment: since the script asks permission for updates, I added user root commands: ```USER root

RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip```

Answer (score 14):

Adding to @vijayraj34 answer

Ensure you add an auto yes for ubuntu to install the updates and pip without requesting user input

Like so

```
RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip
```

Comment: I'm receiving Unable to locate package y. It will work if you replace "- y" with "-y" in the second line

Answer (score 13):

You have to install pip first.

```
FROM iron/python:2.7
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN set -xe \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install python-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

Comment: adding that line of code give:

    Step 4/7 : RUN set -xe     && apt-get update     && apt-get install python-
    pip
     ---> Running in 0cca59ad3d01
    + apt-get update 
    /bin/sh: apt-get: not found. Seems like commands like apt-get that should be there aren't found at all when the image is being created.

Comment: I have checked the image iron/python:2.7. That not use debian base. You can try change to use FROM python:2.7-slim instead of FROM iron/python:2.7

Comment: Package 'python-pip' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

`RUN set -xe && apt-get -yqq update && apt-get -yqq install python3-pip && pip3 install --upgrade pip`

for me worked with pip3

Comment: Please format any bash commands using code formatting "backticks" (like `this`).  This will make it easier for potential readers to copy and paste your suggested command.